# Can I control the ringer volume based on a timer/clock?

Tags: iphone, ios, do-not-disturb

My wife leads a very scheduled life.  She has a meeting every morning from 6 to 8 am and does not want it interrupted by phone rings or text boops, so she sets the phone to silent.  And never turns it back.  So it is nearly impossible to call her.

Simple solution, use clock to turn to silent and back to active.  Nope, doesn't do that.  Must be an app for that!  Nope.  A few apps claim so but actually just set timers to remind you to turn it back on and, since it is in silent mode, they just flash the screen.  Which does little good in a purse.

How can we accomplish this either with built-in functionality or with an app?

Answer (score 7):

Apple does not allow apps to "play with" that system setting. That's the technical reason why there's no app for it. It might be able using a jailbreak tweak if it has to change every day (for example: monday between 2 and 4, tuesday between 2 and 3 etc.)

However if you go to:

1. **Settings**
2. **Do not disturb**
3. **Scheduled**
4. Pick the time of your desire
5. You're done

Comment: Even I felt the someway. But there are few apps that gives this functionality 1. https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/autosilent/id474777148?mt=8 2. https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/auto-mute-by-location/id650303758?mt=8

Answer (score 4):

You could use **Do not Disturb** mode. Found under **Settings / Do Not Disturb** or in **Control Center** (the moon icon), this mode silents calls, alerts and notifications and it can be scheduled to be automatically enabled between specified hours.

Answer (score 0):

iphone 3gs:   Settings > Notifications > Do not disturb > scheduled slide to ON > set from and to > hope this is OK