# How can I make iPhone silent for a specific amount of time?

Tags: iphone, ios, automation, sound-volume

On Android phones, there are apps (not native functionality) to make the phone silent **for the next N minutes starting right now**. This is different than setting specific times of day *like Do Not Disturb does*.

The functionality I'm used to takes one of two forms:

- An icon you click that then asks "how long should the silence last"
- Or, automatically detect that I turned off the sound to zero (via volume rockers or otherwise); and asks the same thing.
- However, I'm not dogmatic, if iPhone has some other approach to solve this problem I'm open to exploring it.

Is something like this available on iPhone? (6, OS version 10 if it matters).

I prefer native functionality if it exists. Otherwise, an App store app is OK as long as it's free (as in gratis) doesn't require jailbreaking and works on iPhone 6.

Extra plus if it supports both modes described above (trigger with the icon or with setting volume to zero); as well as supposed 100% silence or vibrate-only mode.

Comment: Take a look at the sidebar 'Upcoming Events', there's a [link](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2180/how-should-i-ask-about-getting-a-software-recommendation?cb=1) there with helpful info on asking for software recommendations.  If you can edit your question after reading that info, it will help us provide a good answer to you.

Comment: @fsb - Thank you. To be honest, I was hoping for a native functionality as preferred answer (otherwise I'd have just asked on Software recs.SE straight away :)

Comment: There is no native function for this so anything that will do it would be an app (except for Do Not Disturb, which probably doesn't fit your needs).  I can't recall any apps that do it, either, but that doesn't mean it doesn't exist.  Hopefully, someone will know of app to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of iOS 12, there are now built-in options for Do Not Disturb that you let you set it in a more granular or "smarter" way. If you go into Control Center and long press on the Do Not Disturb icon, you're now presented with four options:

- For 1 hour
- Until this evening
- Until I leave this location
- Until the end of this event

There are also two other modes available in Settings > Do Not Disturb:

- Do Not Disturb While Driving: this will enable Do Not Disturb either automatically (based on detected speed) or whenever you're connected to your car's Bluetooth. You can also turn this on and off manually from Control Center
- Do Not Disturb During Bedtime: this is an additional option to scheduled Do Not Disturb that will also dim the lock screen and send all incoming notifications to your history (so you can review them after DND ends)

Short of using a Siri shortcut, I don't think there's any way to set Do Not Disturb for an exact number of minutes, but the above options will probably cover most situations in which you'd want to do that.

Comment: You can have a look at my answer :)

Answer (score 4):

While time-limited muting does exist on Android, it does not on iOS. You can set your phone to silent (by using the mute switch on the side of the phone), but you can't set it to silent *for N hours*. This feature could come in a future software update (try [suggesting it to Apple](http://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html)) but can't come from an app, as iOS apps are forbidden from controlling ringer volume or Do Not Disturb setting.

You can, however, set DND to come on for a specific time period every night, having it automatically turn on at 10pm and turn off at 7am, say (times are customizable). That's in `Settings`->`Do Not Disturb`->`Scheduled`.

[image: Scheduled DND]

Source of information about apps not being able to control ringer volume: my personal knowledge as a published iOS developer and [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/123056/1806360).

Comment: Thanks, but the second part of the answer (DnD) is explicitly what I didn't want - simply didn't know formal Apple term for it.

Comment: If you have a reference to apps not being permitted to control volume, i'll accept the answer

Comment: @DVK I only mention scheduled DnD because it's literally the only way to schedule your iPhone being quiet, which is related to what you asked for. And what do you have against DnD (why would you prefer regular muting)? I also included a reference, basically it's from my knowledge as an iOS developer ([you can check out my apps](http://onestudio.gq/my-apps), shameless plug) and another answer to a similar question.

Comment: DnD is only on a fixed schedule, as far as I understand, which is why i'm against it. I need to do "I have an unscheduled 15 mins where I don't want my iPhone making sounds, starting right now". If DnD could do that, it would work

Comment: @DVK Understood. Unfortunately, you can't do that :(.

Comment: Hm.... I don't mean to sound ungrateful but your reference is to *another* un-referenced SE answer :) I was hoping for something Apple-docs sourced, to be honest :)

Comment: @DVK I looked...unfortunately there was nothing in the Apple docs. Weird. Actually, I just found this app (that looks really sketchy and costs $3) that claims to silence your phone on a timer. Worth a try, maybe? https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/autosilent-automatically-silence/id474777148?mt=8

Comment: @owlswipe see if the solution I have provided does what you people need or not

Answer (score 1):

In the “correct” and most voted answer comment, you’ve suggested that an on the spot DnD timing would be preferable over the scheduled one. The screenshot I have added is from shortcuts app and does exactly that. Also if you you follow the other shortcut you can enter the time in text format till which you want dnd to be turned on. Furthermore, with some better skills, I hope one can use the time provided in the siri command just like in the other answer and its comments, it is 3 hours. [image: shortcut] 
[image]

Comment: Sorry for n00b questiuon but how do you get to that shortcut?

Comment: Told you! Shortcut app!  Also you can change “correct answer”.

Answer (score -1):

"siri, please mute phone calls for the next 3 hours!"

Comment: How does this address all the other notifications from the iPhone?  This will not silence other alarms or text messages.

Comment: I'm far more interested in muting notifications than phone calls.

Comment: probably: siri, do not disturb me for the next 3 hours.

Comment: "Siri, can you STFU for about 10 minutes, I'm trying to think"

Comment: I just tried that and she said I can’t do that.