# Is there anyway to set up more than one do not disturb schedule on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, do-not-disturb

I would like to have it so my phone has do not disturb on at night, and then have it turn on later in the day as well. As far as I know, you can only set up one schedule in settings. Is there an app/something else that would allow me to do this?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/265962/how-can-i-make-iphone-silent-for-a-specific-amount-of-time/354003#354003 See if you're willing to use shortcuts

Comment: Is there a way I can schedule it? For example DND from 11PM to 6AM then 8AM to 1PM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use bedtime in DND for night and the scheduled DND for the daytime. See in Do Not Disturb settings -> Scheduled for enabling Bedtime and then go to clock app for setting its time. This solves night. For day, use the scheduled feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can set bed time, DND(Do not disturb) and downtime (under screen time) so that you only receive notifications at three intervals a day.